Geometry Nodes: Is it possible to rotate a point?
Is it possible to rotate a point or points in geometry nodes? I mean before using the points to place instances on them? I know how to rotate instances.
But would the animation framerate increase if you rotate points first instead of rotating instances later?

To answer your first question: A point has no size and no rotation. But you can assign any attributes to a point.
Depending on how you use these values in your setup, you can do this with the  Capture Attribute or Store Named Attribute nodes, for example.
The basic rule here is: Use Capture Attribute if Store Named Attribute is not absolutely necessary, otherwise you would store additional data in the geometry that is no longer needed in the end and would only fill up the memory.

To answer your second question: This depends on your setup.
If you compare both scenarios in the simplest case, there is really no difference in terms of performance.

(Storing the rotation as attributes in the point domain before instantiation)

(Transforming the objects after instantiation)
However, it can become significantly more computationally expensive under certain circumstances if, for example, you first instantiate objects at the points, then realize the objects and then rotate the mesh. So it really depends on your setup which approach is more performant.
Therefore, the general rule is: If possible, apply any processing to those parts of your geometry that are structurally decisive for your final result at the beginning and that occupy little memory.

Thank you. So basically realising geometry and transforming it later increate the calculation rate. Doing it before this steps keeps everything basically faster.

There is no built-in attribute for such use case. You just need to store some named rotation on points.

Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few images illustrating some steps and final result. See How to write a good answer?, otherwise it may be converted to a comment.
